# Как ограничить количество отображаемых объектов через jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть список отображаемых фильтров, нужно чтобы из них отображались только первые 2, остальные раскрывались по клику на кнопку "смотреть больше", и в раскрытом блоке была кнопка, которая снова сворачивает список с текстом "скрыть".

Пытался сделать так:

```js
var filit = 2; // - количество отображаемых новостей
hidefilit = "- скрыть старые новости";
showfilit = "+ показать все новости";
$(".archive").html(showfilit);
$(".fil-it:not(:lt(" + filit + "))").hide();
$(".archive").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(".news:eq(" + filit + ")").is(":hidden")) {
    $(".fil-it:hidden").show();
    $(".archive").html(hidefilit);
  } else {
    $(".fil-it:not(:lt(" + filit + "))").hide();
    $(".archive").html(showfilit);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-box-list">
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 1
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 2
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 3
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 4
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 5
  </div>
  <a class="archive" href="#"></a>
</div>

<div class="filter-box-list">
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 6
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 7
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 8
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 9
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 10
  </div>
  <a class="archive" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: где в разметке элементы с классом _.news_

Comment: Да, отредактировал. С кодом разобрался, но столкнулся со следующей проблемой: как сделать так, чтобы этот код работал в пределах блока .filter-box-list ? У меня будет несколько таких блоков, и нужно чтобы он независимо от других работал. Сейчас же сразу все элементы сворачивает.

Понимаю, что могу дать класс каждому родителю и стучаться через него, но верно ли такое решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var filit = 2; // - количество отображаемых новостей

hidefilit = "- скрыть старые новости";
showfilit = "+ показать все новости";

$(".archive").html(showfilit);

$(".fil-it:nth-child(n + " + (filit + 1) + ")").hide();

$(".archive").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if ($(this).siblings(".news:eq(" + filit + ")").is(":hidden")) {
    $(this).siblings(".fil-it:hidden").show(400);
    $(this).html(hidefilit);
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(".fil-it:nth-child(n + " + (filit + 1) + ")").hide(400);
    $(this).html(showfilit);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-box-list">
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 1
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 2
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 3
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 4
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 5
  </div>
  <a class="archive" href="#"></a>
</div>

<div class="filter-box-list">
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 6
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 7
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 8
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 9
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it">
    Пункт 10
  </div>
  <a class="archive" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А скажите пожалуйста ещё, как сделать их анимированным? типа выезжающий список

Comment: просто в параметрах `show()` и `hide()` укажите кол-во миллисекунд - я обновил код и для примера поставил 400

Comment: Спасибо! То, что я искал.

Comment: И ещё один вопрос, если не затруднит ответить.. Я пытаюсь вставить в переменную html код, но он не отображается. Почему так? Пытался без переменной напрямую вставлять.
showfilit = "<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> смотреть больше";

Comment: можете создать пример того, что не работает на CodePen, JSBin или JSFiddle?

Comment: Разобрался. Оказывается кавычки двойные были.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```js
var filit = 2; // - количество отображаемых новостей
hidefilit = "- скрыть старые новости";
showfilit = "+ показать все новости";
var text='';
for(var x=0;x < 10 ;x++){
  if(x>1){
    text +="<div class='news fil-it no_active'>Пункт " + (x+1) + "</div>";
  }else{
    text +="<div class=' fil-it'>Пункт " + (x+1) + "</div>";
  }
}
text += "<br><span class='toggle'>>>>> click me </span>";
$(".filter-box-list").append(text);
$(".no_active").hide();
$(".active").show();
$(".toggle").click(function(){
  $(".news").toggle("no_active");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-box-list">
</div>
```

**UPD:**

```js
$(".no_active").hide();
$(".active").show();
$(".toggle").click(function(){
  $(".news").toggle("no_active");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-box-list">
  <div class=" fil-it">
    Пункт 1
  </div>
  <div class=" fil-it">
    Пункт 2
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it no_active">
    Пункт 3
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it no_active">
    Пункт 4
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it no_active">
    Пункт 5
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it no_active">
    Пункт 6
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it no_active">
    Пункт 7
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it no_active">
    Пункт 8
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it no_active">
    Пункт 9
  </div>
  <div class="news fil-it no_active">
    Пункт 10
  </div>
  <br>
  <span class="toggle"> >>>> click me </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но код должен вставляться через html. У вас через jquery

Comment: @Александр не понял в чем разница, но добавил не динамическое..